# Solution of general linear SDE system

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

**Introduction**

I have a multidimensional, inhomogeneous SDE system:

$$ d\underline{X}(t) = \left[\underline{\underline{A}}(t) \cdot \underline{X}(t) + \underline{a}(t) \right] \cdot dt + \sum_{m = 1}^{M} \left[\underline{\underline{B_m}}(t) \cdot \underline{X}(t) + \underline{b_m}(t) \right] \cdot dW_m(t) , \quad (1) $$

where we know by the Ludwig Arnold book (https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1018036?mobileUi=0) that the inhomogeneous solution is the following:

$$ \underline{X}(t) = \underline{\underline{\Phi}}(t) \cdot \left[ \underline{X}_0 + \int_0^t \underline{\underline{\Phi}}^{-1}(s) \cdot \left( \underline{a}(s) - \sum_{m = 1}^{M} \underline{\underline{B_m}}(s) \cdot  \underline{b_m}(s) \right) ds + \sum_{m = 1}^{M} \int_0^t \underline{\underline{\Phi}}^{-1}(s) \cdot \underline{b_m}(s) dW_m(s) \right] , \quad (2) $$

where $\underline{\underline{\Phi}}(t)$ function has to be calculated by

$$ d\underline{\underline{\Phi}}(t) = \underline{\underline{A}}(t) \cdot \underline{\underline{\Phi}}(t) \cdot dt + \sum_{m = 1}^{M} \underline{\underline{B_m}}(t) \cdot \underline{\underline{\Phi}}(t) \cdot dW_m(t) , \quad (3) $$

equation and it has no explicit general form.

**Question**

If $\underline{\underline{A}}(t)$ and $\underline{\underline{B}}(t)$ has special properties (commutation) the I think equation 3 can be calculated in the following form:

$$ \underline{\underline{\Phi}}(t) = \underline{\underline{1}} \cdot e^{\int_0^t \underline{\underline{A}}(s) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m = 1}^{M} \underline{\underline{B_m}}^2(s) ds + \sum_{m = 1}^{M} \int_0^t  \underline{\underline{B_m}}(s) dW_m(s)} , \quad (4) $$

If equation (4) is true, why is equation (1) not solveable? Im I correct if I calculate $\underline{\underline{\Phi}}(t)$ function with equation (4) using numerical integration? Can $\underline{X}(t)$ be solved stronger than simulation if I use the equations (2) and (4) but make the integrations numerically if I must?

Thank you very much for the answers!

Comment: How do you know that they commute?

Comment: In my case $\underline{\underline{B}}$ matrix is almost zero matrix, only (1,1) component is not zero

Comment: That's useful. How about $A(t)$, do they commute at different times?

Comment: In my case only (1,1) component of $\underline{\underline{A}}$ has time dependency, the other components are constants

Comment: They still might not commute with each other, right? I mean $[A(t_1),A(t_2)] \neq 0$. If everything commutes, you can find a common basis and decouple to ODE's. Otherwise, you need the full blown expression.

Comment: I think $[A(t_1),A(t_2)] \neq 0$ is not required only $[A(t_n),B_m(t_n)] = 0$ for all $t_n$. But it seems that a symmetric $\underline{\underline{A}}$ likes to commute with diagonal $\underline{\underline{B}}$, so I was not right when I wrote they commute.

Comment: It looks like the solution is truly almost impossible if $\underline{\underline{B}}(t) \neq 0$. But if it is what is the solution? In case $\underline{\underline{B}}(t) = 0$, is it solveable?