Solution to General Linear Vector-Valued SDE w/ Diagonal Noise?
While the scalar case has a well known solution, does a closed-form solution exist for the vector-valued case where the diffusion matrix is diagonal? To be precise, $\vec{X}(t)$ is a $N$-dimensional vector-valued stochastic process, $A(t)$ and $C(t)$ are $N \times N$ matrices, $B(t)$ and $D(t)$ are $N$-dimensional column vector, and each element of $\vec{W}(t)$ is an independent Wiener process.
$d\vec{X}(t) = \left(A(t) \vec{X}(t) + B(t) \right)dt +  diag\left(C(t) \vec{X}(t) + D(t) \right)d\vec{W}(t)$
If it helps my specific case involves $A(t) = A$, $C(t)=\mathbf{0}_{N\times N}$, and $D(t) = D$.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4207528/1133926 for the general linear case. With $A(t) = A$, $C(t)=0$, and $D(t) = D$, each component of $\vec{X}$ will correspond to an independent Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

@Abezhiko Thank you! The reference is very helpful.

@Abezhiko If $B_i(t) = \alpha_i + \beta_{1,i} Y_t + \beta_{2,i} Z_t + \beta_{3,i} Y_t^2 + \beta_{4,i} Z_t^2 + \beta_{5,i} Y_t Z_t$ where $X_t, Y_t$ are independent mean zero OU processes, are you sure the system can still be decoupled? In my set-up the first variable is linear in $Y_t$, the second variable is linear in $Z_t$, and the third variable is quadratic in $Y_t$ and $Z_t$.

I think I answered my own question. Since $Z_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent of $\vec{X}_t$ the decoupling still holds. What might change is that the first and second variable will now depend both on $Z_t$ and $Y_t$ however.
